# Why is the result of datediff year in Firebird too high?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have question about function datediff in firebird. When I try to diff two dates like 15.12.1999 and 30.06.2000 in sql like this

```
SELECT
SUM(datediff (YEAR, W.FROM, W.TO)),
SUM(datediff (MONTH, W.FROM, W.TO)),
SUM(datediff (DAY, W.FROM, W.TO))
FROM WORKERS W
WHEN W.ID=1
```

I get in result 1 year, 6 month and 198 days but it is not true with value years (of course result should be 0) How I have to write my query to get correct result in parameter year? In that link https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-datediff.html in documentation there is information about this case but there is not how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is not very clear, but I'm pretty sure that `datediff()` is counting the number of boundaries between two dates.  (This is how the very similar function in SQL Server works.)  Hence, for `year`, it is counting the number of "Dec 31st/Jan 1st" boundaries.  *This* is explicitly explained in the documentation.

If you want a more accurate count, you can use a smaller increment.  The following is pretty close:

```
(datediff(day, w.from, t.to) / 365.25) as years_diff
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, I try to use your solution but it doesn`t works in other date 1971-09-28 to 1972-10-25 result is 0.

Comment: Hi, Sorry Gordon for my mistake, it works correctly. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The behaviour is documented (_"DATEDIFF doesn't look at any smaller units than the one specified in the first argument"_ followed by a similar example). Do you have an idea how the documentation could be improved?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel . . . You can read SQL Server's documentation on `datediff()`.  It is much clearer on this point.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. I'll see if I can rewrite it.